# Use JDK from Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse

We are using Eclipse for our projects and we would like to revision control the JDK we use.  (Different projects need to use different JDKs).  Instead of configuring everyone's system to have the same JDK with the same names in Eclipse, we would like to include the JDK as part of our project in our source control tool and have the project point to the JDK that is part of the project.

We can't figure out how to tell Eclipse to use the JDK that is found in the project.  It keeps wanting an absolute path to the JDK.  Is it possible to use the JDK that is part of a project and use a path that is relative to the project?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use the JDK that is part of a project and use a path
>   that is relative to the project?

Straight answer: **NO**

You're asking to go around the basic abstraction that Eclipse provides between installed runtime environments (which are defined at the workspace level) and the project's compiler configuration (which is defined at the project level). If you want to use all the JDT features in Eclipse, you just have to live with configuring the [installed JREs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-add_new_jre.htm) on each workspace of each of your developers.

However, I can think of a probably not-so-standard-way (I see the -1's coming for saying this, which is crazy!) to achieve what you want: to distribute the `.metadata` folder of a pre-configured workspace you've already set up with all your JRE's so you don't have to go on each machine and do the installation. This would also include committing the `.settings` folder and the `.project .classpath` files of each project. Want to include the JDKs? Well, you could put each of them in the SCM as individual projects and ask each developer to import and configure them. If you did this on your template workspace before distributing it, then it will have not only the JDK's but also the `.metadata` pointing to them.

What could go wrong with this? **probably everything.**

How do the pro's do it? Maven and the `maven-compiler-plugin` (and not committing any IDE specific files). This leaves developers free to choose any IDE they want, and most of them support automatic project configuration from POM files: target JDK, dependencies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the approach you are looking for, but one option is to use a drive letter using `SUBST`  for the root directory of your project.

Having the same path to project on all development machines has many advantages. This strategy is most useful for developers working on a single codeline but I have successfully used it even with multiple codelines on my machine, changing the subst as necessary.

Comment: This approach is our backup plan.  We'd rather not have to force everyone to have the same environment.  People consistently ignore or don't know about the specified structure.  It becomes some what of a management night mare.  It'd be more simple if we could just check out the project and it'd compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the JDK version in Eclipse. Right click your project, select properties, goto Java Compiler and there you can select a project specific version of Java for your project.

Comment: I need to set more than just the version.  I need to set the path to the JDK.  Different developers have JDKs in different locations and some don't have the correct JDK pre-installed.

Comment: I think it is not worth the trouble putting the JDK into source control for that purpose. The JDK is THE vital tool and each developer should just be told to install the correct version. I assume a developer to be able to install a JDK on its own.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to install all the JDKs on all the machines and use JAVA_HOME/PATH variables to point the appropriate JDK installation as required. You can write a simple batch file to take care of environment variable setting by just a simple double click.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

Either use Maven to just declare all your dependencies, including the SDK to be used. Or use [Yoxos](https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/) or [Secure Delivery Center](http://www.genuitec.com/sdc/) to centrally define Eclipse configurations, which are then deployed to your developers desk on starting Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

You're checking in the entire JDK? That seems likely to slow down your SCM quite a bit as it has to try and track a lot of large binaries, which won't diff well. Why not use a tool like Maven that declaratively states what JRE version to use?

Comment: We're using Eclipse to develop.  Mavin isn't a development tool.  We could hack something together, but we'd rather not.  There is a Mavin-Eclipse plugin, but again, that isn't really the intent of Mavin and it is cumbersome to use.

The JDK isn't that big and we're on an internal Gigabit network and there won't be diffs (in the JDK) to worry about.  Any performance hits won't be noticed.

Comment: @Thor What the plugins do is make your IDE use the Maven POM to declare dependencies and set up the build environment instead of their own built-in mechanisms. What Maven is in fact for is letting you build your project automatically independently of an IDE, and as a corollary let your developers use whichever IDE they prefer. It's a valid choice to not want to bother mavenising a project, but you should do that if it's less effort than doing so.

Comment: @TomG: -1: This isn't even an answer.

Comment: @millimoose Which plugin are you referring too?  I'll look into it.  Will I loose intellisense and auto-complete and things like that?  
   
Though, I want to make sure Eclipse doesn't support this natively before I go that far.

Comment: @Thor I'd try [`m2eclipse`](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse). That said this isn't a recommendation, I'm an IntelliJ IDEA user. You shouldn't really lose any functionality, most of what the plugins do is set up Maven dependencies in your project, and let you do Maven builds from the IDE. Also, I should point out that converting an *existing* project to Maven is a fair bit of work, and might not be worth the effort if you find an easier way to handle the JDK versions. (Although that's not the only benefit to using it.)

Comment: @millimoose I'd refer you to http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx The OP's question implies, to me, a lack of familiarity with what I'd consider the proper way of handling this. Also, the top answer right now also suggests Maven as the proper way of handling this issue.

Comment: @TomG My objection isn't just to the fact that your answer boils down to nothing besides "use Maven". It's that most of the answer is just an expression of your bewilderment. That the rest of it isn't very helpful just makes things worse - why not show *how* to make Maven use a JDK that's stored in the project?

Comment: @TomG Also, I don't agree that the blog post you linked to applies. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with the OP's approach. It's not unreasonable to keep all your dependencies under source control - you might be pedantic about repeatability. It's not unreasonable to not want to convert an existing project to Maven, especially a complex one - it's a lot of work that probably requires development to stop while you shuffle the directories around. It's also not unreasonable to have started projects tied to Eclipse - Eclipse was the 800lb gorilla way before Maven.